# AssertJ combine exception catching and return type assertions

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertj

I have a method which catches an `IOException` while trying to process a JSON file and if this exception occurs `false` is being returned. Something like:

```
public boolean method(){
 try{
  // process json file
   return true;
 } catch IOException {
   // write stuff into db
   return false;
 }
}
```

The catch block writes exception message to the database. So given a method with a `boolean` return type and exception handling how can I combine both in my unit test to assert the instance of the exception/its message and method's return value?
I am aware of

```
Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> objectUnderTest.method()).isInstanceOf(IOException.class)
```

The above statement results in: `java.lang.AssertionError: Expecting code to raise a throwable.`

and

```
Assertions.assertThat(objectUnderTest.method()).isFalse() // works well
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception is caught in the method, AssertJ has no chance to see it, hence the assertion error you already experienced.

Assuming you are in a unit test with a mock of the DB writer, you might intercept that call of the mock and assert the invocation parameter(s).

If you aren't in a unit test, you should read back from the DB and assert its content.